# Is there a certain page I should be fetching my API data from within my Chrome Extension Project?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that fetched JSON data from CoinMarketCap.com API and currently I have it running in the background script. I'm not 100% sure what the purpose of the page is really. I was wondering if I could simply fetch the data from the popup script after I click a button within my popup?

Each button represents a different coin. I basically want to get the price of a chosen coin and display it on whatever page the user is on when they double click the coin in a text article. Eventually I want to make it so you can double click any coin and have it show a live price conversion while you're on the web-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a background page is to be always available (running if `persistent: true`, woken up / recreated for registered events if `persistent: false`).

A popup's lifetime is determined by its visibility. The moment the user clicks away and closes it, the page is closed (as if the tab with it was closed), so it can no longer process any events and its state is lost.

As long as:

1. The data you need fetched is to be received/processed while the popup is open
2. Any state you need to persist between popups being shown can be stored in `chrome.storage`

Then you don't need the background page to do the fetching. Popup page has the same level of access to Chrome APIs.

However, consider this scenario: suppose you want the data to be ready as soon as popup is opened (at least, you want it to be fresher than "since last time"). You may want to do periodic updates even while the popup is closed to refresh the data. You can only do that reliably with a background page (and, say, `chrome.alarms` API). Then you can cache the latest available data in `chrome.storage` and use that in the popup.

Background pages have their uses as some code that can run periodically regardless of user actions, and to be able to always react to events.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Changes to Cross-Origin Requests in Chrome Extension Content Scripts](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) now you have to do your fetches in Background Script. Not in Content Script.